# Vite - dist is not inside project root and will not be emptied. Use --emptyOutDir to override

Tags: reactjs, vite

I am trying to set up my vite paths.

This is my current Vite config file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { createHtmlPlugin } from 'vite-plugin-html';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  root: 'src',
  publicDir: '../public',
  build: {
    outDir: '../dist'
  },
  plugins: [
    createHtmlPlugin({
      inject: {
        data: {}
      }
    }),
    react({
      include: '**/*.{jsx,tsx}'
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      '@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets'),
      '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components'),
      '@layouts': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/layouts'),
      '@pages': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/pages')
    }
  }
});
```

Problem that I face:

When I use npm run build the app builds up but I get this error:
`dist is not inside project root and will not be emptied. Use --emptyOutDir to override.`

Unfortunately dist and public folder must not be located in src folder. When I set root to root: "./", and change to outDir: './dist', publicDir: './public' my app is not achivable at localhost after running npm run dev.

I tried to reconfigure path to entry point files however it does not solve the problem at all. In fact it causes application to stop working on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Edit package.json and change the build line from:

```
 "scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "vite build",
    ...
  },
```

to:

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "vite build --emptyOutDir",
    ...
  },
```

This will ensure your dist folder is properly emptied and will also prevent the error.